# Prove that $f'(x)$ is constant from $2(f'(x))^2 + f(x)f''(x)=c$, c constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was fiddling around with derivatives of functions and messed up a question so badly that I was left with the above expression and the knowledge that $f(0)=0$. To proceed, I assumed $f'(x)=\text{constant}$ for all $x$ and that gave me the answer to the problem. I also know from solving it with another method that there really exists only 1 function $f(x)$. The problem is, if a non-constant $f'(x)$ could be found, there would exist another solution to the problem, which I know to not be the case, so $f'(x)$ should be constant, and provable from the above equation and knowing $f(x)=0$. If so, how do we go about proving it?

For the curious, the original question stated that, for a continuous and differentiable $g(x)$, define $f(x)$ to be $f(x)=g''(x)$ and $g(x)=kf^3(x)$ for a constant $k$, and $g(0)=g'(0)=0$. You arrive at my equation by taking the derivative of both sides of the equation twice and simplifying it by $f(x)$ (we are given that $f(x)$ is not $0$ for all $x$).

Comment: Writing mathematics is not writing for a computer. Please do not use $*$ for multiplication.

Comment: It's simpler to prove that $f'$ is constant by solving $g=k(g'')^3$.

Comment: Interestingly, without the hypothesis that $f(0)=0$, you find that $f(x)=(ax+b)^{1/3}$ solves your equation with $k=0$.

Comment: Does this have a simpler, analytical solution?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon, as Gonçalo stated, you can solve it directly from $g = k(g'')^3$. 

Observe that $dg/dg' × dg'/dx = dg/dx = g'$. Write $g''$ instead of $dg'/dx$. After shifting some expressions, you can see that $g''×dg = g'×dg'$. We can then take their integrals. RHS will be $(g')^2/2$, and we can convert the whole equation to $g'=dg/dx=r×g^(2/3)$ where r is a constant dependant on k. Take the integrals of $g^(-2/3) dg=r×dx$ and you'll find $g$. Note that $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ so the integral constant are 0.

PS: I'm having trouble writing g^(-2/3), the fraction is supposed to be the power.

Comment: How is this the solution to the first qn?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon, my apologies. I thought you were referring to the original question from which I had arrived at the title question. While the original question is homogenous, the title question is not. It's also somewhat more complicated, so I doubt that a pretty solution exists since the solution to $g=k(g'')^3$ itself is already a bit messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show that
$$
2(f')^2+ff''=c \tag{1}
$$
and $f(0)=0$ --- plus the condition that $f'$ is continuous$^{(*)}$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$ --- imply $f'=$ constant. Indeed,
$$
f''=\frac{df'}{dx}=\frac{df'}{df}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df'}{df}f'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{df}(f')^2, \tag{2}
$$
hence, defining $u=(f')^2$, we can rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
2u+\frac{1}{2}f\frac{du}{df}=c &\implies f\frac{du}{df}+4u-2c=0 \\
&\implies 4f^3\left(f\frac{du}{df}+4u-2c\right)=0 \\
&\implies \frac{d}{df}[f^4(4u-2c)]=0 \\ 
&\implies f^4[4(f')^2-2c]=A.\phantom{\frac{d}{df}} \tag{3}
\end{align}
Since $f(0)=0$ and $f'$ is continuous at $x=0$, we conclude that $A=0$. It then follows from $(3)$ that $f=0$ or $4(f')^2-2c=0$; in both cases, $f'=$ constant.

---

$^{(*)}$ Without this condition, Eq. $(1)$ may admit a solution $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ but $f'\neq$ constant. For instance, $f(x)=Ax^{1/3}$ is a solution to $(1)$ if $c=0$; in this case, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}Ax^{-2/3}$. However, if we require that $f'$ be continuous at $x=0$, then $f=f'=0$.

---

EDITED: The derivation of Eq. $(3)$ was replaced with a new one, in order to avoid a problem in the previous one pointed out by @HideBehind.

Comment: Thank you for updating your solution. I find it impressive how you are able to see exactly where to integrate to find an easier-to-work-with equation, I hope I can reach that intuition one day.

Answer (score 1):

Using computer algebra software I get the two solutions to $f'(x)$ as:

$$f_{\pm}'(x)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{c\, \left(\alpha_{\pm} ^{(-1)}(x)\right)^4-e^{4 \gamma }}}{\sqrt{2} \left(\alpha_{\pm} ^{(-1)}(x)\right)^2}\,,$$

with $\gamma$ an arbitrary constant and

$$\alpha_{\pm}(x)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2} x^3 \sqrt{1-c e^{-4 \gamma } x^4} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{7}{4};c\,e^{-4 \gamma } x^4\right)}{3 \sqrt{cx^4-e^{4 \gamma }}}\,,$$

where $_2F_1$ is the Gaussian hypergeometric function. Whatever this monstrosity is, I verified numerically it is not constant.

In the limit of the integration constant $\gamma \to -\infty$ the exponentials get killed off, and ignoring branch cut complications the expression simplifies to

$$f_{\pm}'(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{c}{2}}\,.$$

So it seems that $f'(x)$ constant seems to not be the general solution to this DEQ, but only a specific limit. Of course we cannot blindly trust whatever a computer spits out as the answer, but it does seem to be at least a good indication that your conjecture may be incorrect.

Comment: I wonder if we can get rid of the non-constant parts by assuming $f'(0)=0$. The equation I used to find 2(′())2+()″()= also gives us that $f'(0)=0$ since $g(0)=0$ is also given. So while the answer to my question seems to be NO, adding $f'(0)=0$ might make that a YES.